# Invalid version constraint: Cannot include other constraints with "^"

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I was studying and practicing basics of Flutter and I got this issue.

Code:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2+
  english_words: ^3.1.0
```

I got error after executing command `--no-color packages get`:

```
Error on line 21, column 20 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Cannot include other constraints with "^" constraint in "^0.1.2+".
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2+
                   ^^^^^^^

pub get failed (65)
```

Development Platform:
Android Studio 3.4 running on Mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 3):

I have ended up coming here after a websearch, the mistake I did was to add a trailing comma

changed this

```
flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5,
```

to

```
flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Current stable version of cupertino_icons is `0.1.2`

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

The caret sign `(^)` is used for pub dependencies in Dart to indicate a range of version numbers are allowed. Specifically, any version from the specified version up to (but not including) the next non-breaking version is ok.

> Remove + sign after 2

Everything before plus is version name and after is version code and you're not specifying any version code, so remove +.